# SQL - Update multiple columns in one table, but one is a foreign key and should only be updated if it exists

Tags: sql

I'm running a simple SQL query to update a couple columns in a table. For all but one column, I want them updated no matter what, but one is a foreign key, and I want to update that only if it exists in another table. I'm using a statement like this:

```
update table1 
set column1 = @var1, column2 = @var2, FK = @var3 
where PK = @var4
```

How do I write this so that column1 and column2 will always be updated, but FK will only be updated if it exists in, say, table2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
update table1
    set column1 = @var1,
        column2 = @var2,
        FK = (case when exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.pk = @var3)
                   then @var3 else FK
              end)
    where PK = @var4;
```

Comment: I almost sure you mean t2.pk, there isnt t1 there.